# Como verificar se uma caixa de texto foi preenchida via querySelector em uma condição?

Tags: javascript, dom

Estou usando DOM pra carregar os dados e gostaria de usar o `if` para dar um `innerHTML` diferente se os campos foram ou não preenchidos. Mas não sei qual valor comparar... No `console.log` apresenta um tal de *empty string*. Ao executar código abaixo ele só entra no `else`/`false`.

```
function liberarUrna(){
  txt_tEleitor = window.document.querySelector('input#txt_tEleitor')
  txt_mVotacao = window.document.querySelector('input#txt_mVotacao')
  tEleitor = String(txt_tEleitor.value)
  mVotacao = String(txt_mVotacao.value)
  //console.log(tEleitor)
  //console.log(mVotacao)
  result = window.document.querySelector('div#result')

  if (tEleitor && mVotacao == "") {
    result.innerHTML = `<p>Favor preencher os campos</p>` 
  }
  result.innerHTML = `<p>Titulo de eleitor: ${tEleitor} <br> Município: ${mVotacao} <br><strong>Urna liberada para votação!</p>` 
}
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade do construtor `String` ali, uma vez que a propriedade `value` já retorna uma string (tecnicamente, `DOMString`, mas tem total compatibilidade com o primitivo `string`). Além disso, poderia tentar **[edit]** a sua pergunta para adicionar um **[mcve]**? Tente adicionar, além do JavaScript, que já está presente na pergunta, o HTML no _snippet_ de código (provido pelo próprio editor de texto) para que possamos reproduzir o seu problema.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, Luiz! Vou verificar isso assim que possivel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece aí é que vc não tem nenhum **`else`** no seu código, e vc **ACHOU** que se não caísse no **if** *(que também está errado)* executaria o outro código como um else, MAS NÃO, toda vez que executar a função independente do if ser `true` ou não o innerHTML que mostra os dados do eleitor sempre será executado, pois ele não está dentro de nehuma condição. Para resolver existe 2 maneiras, ou, coloca o código com os dados do eleitor dentro de um else ou insere um **`return`** no if, o que fará parar a execução da função ali.

O seu if também está errado, faltou verificar se o input  `txt_tEleitor` está vazio, do jeito que fez apenas o input `txt_mVotacao` está sendo verificado se contém valor ou está vazio. Outro erro é que vc utilizou o operador de comparação **`&&`**, ou seja, para retornar o que está dentro do if os 2 inputs teriam que estar vazio, o que não é correto, se um input já estiver vazio já deverá mostrar a mensagem de preencher os campos:

```js
function liberarUrna(){
  txt_tEleitor = document.querySelector('input#txt_tEleitor');
  txt_mVotacao = document.querySelector('input#txt_mVotacao');
  tEleitor = txt_tEleitor.value;
  mVotacao = txt_mVotacao.value;
  result = document.querySelector('div#result')

  if (tEleitor == '' || mVotacao == '') {
    return result.innerHTML = `<p>Favor preencher os campos</p>`
  }
  result.innerHTML = `<p>Titulo de eleitor: ${tEleitor} <br> Município: ${mVotacao} <br><strong>Urna liberada para votação!</p>`
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_tEleitor">
<input type="text" id="txt_mVotacao">
<button onclick="liberarUrna()">Votar</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

> **OBS 1:** Como dito no comentário do Luiz, não precisa converter o valor do input para string, pois o valor retornado pelos inputs já são compatíveis com o tipo string.

> **OBS: 2** Não precisa declarar o objeto window antes de document, pois window já é o elemento raíz de uma página web, logo, na estrutura de árvore do DOM document já pertence a window.

Comment: Muito obrigado, LeAndrade. Esclareceu muitas coisas!